# If Rank() is tied: Make a row True depending on the value within a column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have a dataframe like below.

I am partitioning by the "ID" and ordering by the "VALUE" desc.

If for an ID there is a tie, take the greater "disc" value.

If the greatest "disc" value is the same then I want to assign "True" to the row where description is "general".

Original df

```
description    id    value  disc  row_number    

general         1      3      1        1           
non-general     1      3      2        1             
general         2      1      1        2                      
non-general     2      3      1        1             
general         3      10     5        1
non-general     3      10     5        1
atypical        3      10     5        1
```

Expected Output

```
description    id    value  disc  row_number    winner

general         1      3      1        1         false    
non-general     1      3      2        1         true          
general         2      1      1        2         false               
non-general     2      3      1        1         true      
general         3      10     5        1         true
non-general     3      10     5        1         false
atypical        3      10     5        1         false
```

What have I tried so far. I've been able to incorporate when and otherwise to work correctly for everything that doesn't have a tie when it comes to "disc". However, when it's ties with "disc" is where I am struggling.

Appreciate anyone's help greatly! I am also very curious on how you guys might handle this problem above. My solution can be improved certainly.

This helps me identify if an "ID" has a tie in the first break but how do I pick the right row to break the tie breaker but keep all rows just mark it true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by descending `value`, then descending `disc`, and finally a Boolean of `description != general`. The final Boolean will prioritise general descriptions because they will give `False`, which ranks lower than `True` for ascending ordering.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy(
    F.desc('value'), 
    F.desc('disc'), 
    F.col('description') != 'general'
)

w2 = Window.partitionBy('id')

df2 = df.withColumn('winner', 
    F.when(
        F.min(F.col('description') != 'general').over(w2),
        F.lit(None)
    ).otherwise(F.row_number().over(w) == 1)
)

df2.show()
+-----------+---+-----+----+----------+------+
|description| id|value|disc|row_number|winner|
+-----------+---+-----+----+----------+------+
|non-general|  1|    3|   2|         1|  true|
|    general|  1|    3|   1|         1| false|
|non-general|  2|    3|   1|         1|  true|
|    general|  2|    1|   1|         2| false|
|    general|  3|   10|   5|         1|  true|
|non-general|  3|   10|   5|         1| false|
|   atypical|  3|   10|   5|         1| false|
+-----------+---+-----+----+----------+------+
```

You can use `rank` instead of `row_number` if there could be multiple rows with the same value, disc and description.

Comment: The only time I am not seeing this work is in this one case. When an ID doesn't have a description of "general" at all. So in this case we would like to leave null. But I didn't explicitly state this. This is very helpful though and I really appreciate you.

Comment: see edited answer? you can add a check for that

Comment: Upvoting thanks! How long you been doing pyspark for? Just started here..

Comment: time isn't really a factor... experience is more important. Work through more of these problems and you'll get better :)

Comment: Hmm the check to set to null if general does not exist is not exactly working hmm. Seems like if general does exist but where the value is null and disc is lower than the rest is where it fails. If that makes sense.

Comment: Figured it out with thinking through it more w/ your help and examples! Appreciate you!